# очень много миграций в laravel

Tags: laravel

кто нибудь подскажите, как вы структурируете миграции, если их почти под сотню? все в одной папке становится непонятно

Comment: Можно хранить несколько миграций в одном файле. Хотя-бы сгрупировать по основному признаку.

Comment: Мне вот интересно другое (оффтоп) как хранить модели, когда их под сотню, миграции то ладно, а вот модели в одной папке не комильфо

Comment: @MoloF дак просто по папка кидаю, по логике что к чему относится, а в миграциях так не сделать, тк при миграции папки внутренние не смотрятся

Comment: Я на одном проекте использовал https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules . Но там больше 250 миграций, просто они раскиданы по разным модулям

Answer (score 0):

одно из самых простых решений, которое я подсмотрел в https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules, - создаешь нужные поддиректории миграций (например `/database/migrations/your_path`) и в `` регистрируешь эти директории в миграторе

```
// config/database.php
return [
// ...
    'migrations_paths' => [
        database_path('migrations/module1'),
        database_path('migrations/module2'),
    ],
// ...
];


// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->afterResolving('migrator', function ($migrator) {
            foreach ((array) config('database.migrations_paths', []) as $path) {
                $migrator->path($path);
            }
        });
    }
}
```